# How to make table from io.read in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to make a Table in lua with io.read, This is my code:

```
local members = {}

io.write("How many members you wanna add? ")
local memberNum = io.read("n")

print("Add new member: ")
for i = 1, memberNum do
    local newMember = io.read("*l")
    if i == 1 then
        members[1] = newMember
    else
        table.insert(members, i, newMember)
    end
end


for i = 1, #members do
    print(i, ": ", members[i])
end
```

I expect to result be:

```
members = { "Amir", "Hamid", "Bahar", "Emad", "Maryam"}
```

but program only accept 4 input from me and insert first input as a **nil** value and give me this result:

```
members = {"", "Amir", "Hamid", "Bahar", "Emad"}
```

What is the problem? Help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's a newline behind the number it reads that the first time you do `io.read("*l")`. The `io.read("n")` only takes the number without the newline. You could make this the input to make it work

```
5Amir
Hamid
Bahar
Emad
Maryam
```

or simply do an extra `io.read("*l")` right after the `local memberNum = io.read("n")`

Comment: I changed `io.read("*n")` to `io.read("n","l')` and its worked. Thanks for replay!